# Find data by multiple Lookup table clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, relational-division

```
declare @Character table (id int, [name] varchar(12));

insert into @Character (id, [name])
values
(1, 'tom'),
(2, 'jerry'),
(3, 'dog');

declare @NameToCharacter table (id int, nameId int, characterId int);

insert into @NameToCharacter (id, nameId, characterId)
values
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 3),
(3, 1, 2),
(4, 2, 1);
```

**The Name Table has more than just 1,2,3 and the list to parse on is dynamic**

NameTable

```
id  | name
----------
1      foo
2      bar
3      steak
```

CharacterTable

```
id | name
---------
1     tom
2     jerry
3     dog
```

NameToCharacterTable

```
id | nameId | characterId
1     1           1
2     1           3
3     1           2
4     2           1
```

I am looking for a query that will return a character that has two names. For example
With the above data only "tom" will be returned.

```
SELECT * 
FROM nameToCharacterTable
WHERE nameId in (1,2)
```

The in clause will return every row that has a 1 or a 3. I want to only return the rows that **have both a 1 and a 3.**

I am stumped I have tried everything I know and do not want to resort to dynamic SQL. Any help would be great

The 1,3 in this example will be a dynamic list of integers. for example it could be 1,3,4,5,.....

Comment: This is a classic relational division question, see eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/70736303/14868997. Do you want to know cases where there are *exactly* those two ("Without Remainder"), or those two and any others ("With Remainder")?

Comment: good question, At minimum of those two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter out a count of how many times the Character appears in the CharacterToName table matching the list you are providing (which I have assumed you can convert into a table variable or temp table) e.g.

```
declare @Character table (id int, [name] varchar(12));

insert into @Character (id, [name])
values
(1, 'tom'),
(2, 'jerry'),
(3, 'dog');

declare @NameToCharacter table (id int, nameId int, characterId int);

insert into @NameToCharacter (id, nameId, characterId)
values
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 3),
(3, 1, 2),
(4, 2, 1);

declare @RequiredNames table (nameId int);

insert into @RequiredNames (nameId)
values
(1),
(2);

select *
from @Character C
where (
    select count(*)
    from @NameToCharacter NC
    where NC.characterId = c.id
    and NC.nameId in (select nameId from @RequiredNames)
) = 2;
```

Returns:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | tom |

Note: Providing DDL+DML as shown here makes it much easier for people to assist you.

Comment: thank you for the edits and quick response, how would this work with a dynamic list? And a dynamic name table not just 1,2,3

Comment: last sentence in the qustion

Comment: upvote for the constructive suggestion about adding table creation sql

Comment: Thats perfect thank you very much. I wouldn't have thought about just getting all of them with the in clause and making sure there were x for them

Answer (score 1):

**This is classic *[Relational Division](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) With Remainder*.**

There are a number of different solutions. [@DaleK has given you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73724358/14868997) an excellent one: inner-join everything, then check that each set has the right amount. This is normally the fastest solution.

If you want to ensure it works with a dynamic amount of rows, just change the last line to

```sql
) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @RequiredNames);
```

Two other common solutions exist.

- Left-join and check that all rows were joined

```sql
SELECT *
FROM @Character c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM @RequiredNames rn
    LEFT JOIN @NameToCharacter nc ON nc.nameId = rn.nameId AND nc.characterId = c.id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(nc.nameId)  -- all rows are joined
);
```

- Double anti-join, in other words: there are no "required" that are "not in the set"

```sql
SELECT *
FROM @Character c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM @RequiredNames rn
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM @NameToCharacter nc
        WHERE nc.nameId = rn.nameId AND nc.characterId = c.id
    )
);
```

A variation on the one from the other answer uses a windowed aggregate instead of a subquery. I don't think this is performant, but it may have uses in certain cases.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM @Character c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM (
      SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER () AS cnt
      FROM @RequiredNames
    ) rn
    JOIN @NameToCharacter nc ON nc.nameId = rn.nameId AND nc.characterId = c.id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = MIN(rn.cnt)
);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/YRW7SDO-)

Comment: Your relational division link doesn't seem to work

Comment: Fixed now, sorry